# setDefaultCloseOperation not working

Tags: java, swing

Just getting started with GUI's and am really baffled with this bit of code, for some reason when I set the default close operation, it does not work, and same when adding components like the JLabel and the TextField. I have extended my class with JFrame, and I have no other JFrames or JPanels with the same name in my program. Oh and also, the setVisible and the setSize still work, it's just when adding components or setting the close operation. Here is the class that calls the method that contains the call for makeWindow().

```
    public static class Play implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        frame.setVisible(false);
        game.playGame();
    }
```

And here is the actual method:

```
    private void makeWindow() {
    JFrame window = new JFrame("Battleships 2.0");
    JPanel canvas = new JPanel();

    JLabel title = new JLabel("Battleships 2.0");
    title.setFont(font);

    JTextField userCoordinates = new JTextField();

    window.setSize(500,500);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setResizable(false);
    window.setVisible(true);

    canvas.setLayout(new BoxLayout(canvas, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    window.add(canvas);
    canvas.add(title);
    canvas.add(userCoordinates);
}
```

Comment: Try using `window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);`

Comment: "I have extended my class with JFrame"... At `JFrame window = new JFrame("Battleships 2.0");` you create a normal `JFrame`, where is "your class"?

Comment: If you have extended your class with JFrame, then why do you make another JFrame (`window`)? Just do the actions on that itself. BTW, that is a bad habit.

Comment: @Hackerdarshi I was going to ask the same.

Comment: you have do it wrong way.but still it should work .since you have extend with jframe `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` is ok.is there any errors ?

Comment: @Hackerdarshi  have tried that but still nothing happens....

Comment: @FastSnail, no there are no error messages....

Comment: What is your expectation? What should happen in your opinion?

Comment: @Alexander I'm just wanting it for the JFrame to close when I hit the top red X. Also I want my components to display, like my JTextField

Comment: @FraserAngus so now when you hit red x nothing happen??

Comment: Then please post your main method. The problem seems to be there, because your code at least makes the "X" and the textfield work.

Comment: @FastSnail, yes that is what is happening, sorry if the code is a bit clunky, I'm brand new to GUI's and still just learning.

Comment: Ok, just found out that my method is fine, it's something to do with my calling. I'll go check it out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have extended JFrame in your class then you don't need to create a JFrame object again in your method.You have used BOXLayout,so your textfield is occupying the entire panel,with the Label appearing on top.
I just modified your code to use FlowLayout and the controls are clearly visible.
Check this:

```
private void makeWindow() {
        // JFrame window = new JFrame("Battleships 2.0");
        setTitle("Battleships 2.0");
        JPanel canvas = new JPanel();

        JLabel title = new JLabel("Battleships 2.0");
        // title.setFont(font);

        JTextField userCoordinates = new JTextField(10);

        setSize(500, 500);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);

        canvas.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        add(canvas);
        canvas.add(title);
        canvas.add(userCoordinates);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks mate, I never realised that, I am new to java so I make mistakes from time to time, yes I can see it is much nicer and easier